# Predicting from glm function gives an "Error in log(time)"

Tags: r, glm, predict, poisson

I'm trying to predict the failure rate using Poisson regression. However, I somehow get an error which I don't understand. Here's my code:

```
library("survival")

poisson.fit = glm(status ~ offset(log(time)) + ph.karno + age, family = "poisson", data = lung)
# Predict for ph.karno = 50 and age = 55
predict(poisson.fit, newdata = data.frame(ph.karno = 50, age = 55), type="response")
```

The error I get says the following:

```
Error in log(time) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: time is probably a string, convert it to numeric, `log("string")` to reproduce the error

Comment: @Clemsang I checked that the time is numeric from str(lung)

Answer (score 1):

`predict` function needs all of the explanatory variables to be specified, including offset variables. Since `time` is not specified in your function call, a default value in `time`, an R function, is passed. This might cause the 'non-numeric argument' error.

You may try running the code with the `time` specified in your call, e.g.

```
predict(poisson.fit, newdata = data.frame(time=20, ph.karno = 50, age = 55), type="response")
```